# Utilizing TLS 1.2 on CentOS 5.11 for use with Paypal IPN

Tags: ssl, openssl, centos5, tls, curl

Our current web stack is installed on a CentOS 5.11 server with Plesk. We are using PHP 5.4, cURL 7.47.1, and openSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008. I am trying to run Paypal IPNs using code based off of the example found here: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php.

The issue is that the handshake is trying to use SSLv3 which appears to not be supported by Paypal (maybe I'm wrong?). I am getting this error: `error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`. I have found other places saying to try a couple things. All of which I have. I have tried using

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 5);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "TLSv1");`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "TLSv1.2");`

None of which have worked. Both cURL and OpenSSL are updated to the most recent port available to CentOS 5.11.

I am hoping that either I am missing something, that there is a way to run the Paypal IPN without TLS, or there is a way to update openSSL to 1.0.1g. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Upgrading to CentOS 6 is not an option.

Comment: Upgrading is your _only_ option. OpenSSL 0.9.8 has no support for TLS 1.2.

Comment: looks like i'll be building a microservice on EC2 then :/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because CentOS 5 is now past end-of-life, so this question relates to an unsupported environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to compile newer version of openssl: https://miteshshah.github.io/linux/centos/how-to-enable-openssl-1-0-2-a-tlsv1-1-and-tlsv1-2-on-centos-5-and-rhel5/

Better way is migrate to new CentOS6 or CentOS7. Plesk has great migration manager tool.